# One query to retrieve from two tables?

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say I have two tables: one stores links and contains a link_id column, and the other stores info on how many times a particular link has been clicked and it contains a count column and the link_id column. What would be the query to the table in order to retrieve all the links along with the info?

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
SELECT l.link_id, l.link, s.count
FROM link l
  LEFT JOIN stats s
  ON l.link_id = s.link_id
```

should get you all the ids, links (regardless of whether they have an entry in the stats table) and the number of times they've been clicked

Answer (score 0):

Say tables are tab1 and tab2.

query: select link,`count` from tab1 inner join tab2 using(link_id)